# Faraday not working on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, google-api, faraday

I'm trying to use Faraday with Rails 4 for Google API Oauth in below code:

```
class GoogleApisController < ApplicationController

    def oauth2callback
        require 'faraday'
        render layout: false

        conn = Faraday.new(:url => 'https://accounts.google.com',:ssl => {:verify => false}) do |faraday|
            faraday.request  :url_encoded
            faraday.response :logger
            faraday.adapter  Faraday.default_adapter
        end

        @result = conn.post '/o/oauth2/token', {'code' => params[:code],
            'client_id' => "some_id",
            'client_secret' => "some_secret",
            'redirect_uri' => "some_redirect_uri",
            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code'}

    end
end
```

But when I do `@result.body.inspect` it doesn't return anything.

So @result return nil and doesn't seem to process at all.

However when I try the above codes in `liveshell` it seems to work.

Is there a reason why this is happening?

Comment: I think its because you are rendering the template before you actually do anything.  If you move the `render` to the last statement does it work?

Comment: Just confirmed it in one of my rails apps.  If you render before you create the `@result` object, the template does not render anything.

Comment: @Eugene you are right! Please put this in answer so I can accept it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to `render` before you instantiate the object you are trying to `render`, the template won't actually have anything in it.  Moving the `render` statement to the bottom of the method will take care of the issue.